# Multiple microservice symfony application share vendor folder

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, share, microservices

We are working on a new web project, with a microservice architecture.

We will need around 5 Front Web project, and about 5 API microservice orchestrate with an API manager.

We plan to use Symfony2 Framework, but I think it will be too Heavy. I mean because by the instance of the composer that will download all around the same library from symfony component, core... and same library used for each project (phpmailer for example).

Actually, I was asking myself about a great sharing strategy for the vendor folder assuming that each SF2 project would use a share vendor folder and compute all library in a unique folder.
We need all the same version for each library in each project.

Does somebody have some experiment on this kind of sharing? Best practices? Is it preferable to have one vendor folder per project?

Open discution !

Cheers.

Comment: Why do you not plan to use SF3 or SF4 for a future project ?

Comment: yes i mean it will be SF3 ... not SF2 sorry ;)

Comment: Modern disk drives are BIG!!! I wouldn't waste hours researching tricky solutions, when running `composer` five times will hardly register on you disk space indicator!

Comment: One vendor directory for multiple projects forces you to use the same version of the dependencies across projects. No twig 1.* for one and 2.* for another one. This and Bens comment together with caching of downloaded packages within composer strongly suggest one vendor per project imo.

Comment: yes as I mentioned "We need all the same version for each library in each project." but i understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the vendor dir to be a shares folder into your composer.json

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "/usr/share/php/composer/vendor"
    }
}
```

Can it help you ?

Comment: with this idea, the vendor-dir is defined for all packages of all projets, it is a too strong constraint

Comment: yes it might be a great idea... i m gonna give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You should not share anything between microservices. This is because you would loose the main benefit of microservices: **you can deploy every microservice independently**.

They should also be loosely coupled. They should be agnostic of the other technologies. This means that if you change from PHP to Java in one microservice then the others would not be affected. In fact they should not even know or care. The same with the database.